# SQL RowNumber Where Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add `WHERE` condition to this;

```
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT A.* from Experiment A INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS 'RN', "+
             "*FROM Experiment) B  ON A.AutoID= B.AutoID AND B.RN between 
             11 and 21 ", con);
```

Here is the full code;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      // sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Select *From Experiment", con);
     sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT A.* from Experiment A INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS 'RN', "+
       "*FROM Experiment) B  ON A.AutoID= B.AutoID AND B.RN between 11 and 21 ", con);


        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Experiment");
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
     }   
}
```

Comment: what is the problem.. ??

Comment: Just add one.. I don't understand your question.

Comment: You probably don't need the join at all. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS  RN,* FROM   Experiment) T WHERE RN BETWEEN 11 AND 21`

Comment: You appear to be a help vampire: http://www.slash7.com/pages/vampires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've abstracted your query into a string variable (note, strings that start with `@` can carry over multiple lines)

```
string sqlQuery = @"
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM Experiment A 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS 'RN', *
        FROM Experiment) B ON A.AutoID = B.AutoID AND B.RN BETWEEN 11 AND 21"

sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
```

To add a **where**, just append it to the string

```
sqlQuery += " WHERE B.RN = @RowNumberFilter AND A.AutoID = @AutoIDFilter";
```

I'm filtering to only show rows that match the row number filter and the AutoId filter

But you need to tell the sql command what the values of the parameters are.

Assuming

```
int rowNumberFilter = "15";
int autoIDFilter = "101";
```

You've got 2 options

```
// options 1
// explicitly add the parameter with the type then set the value
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RowNumberFilter", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlcmd.Parameters["@RowNumberFilter"].Value = customerID;

// option 2
// implicitly add the parameter using AddWithValue(..) to convert the type
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutoIDFilter", autoIDFilter);
```

Its good practice to use parameters instead of concatinating the values directly into the query.

Eg **this is bad**

```
sqlQuery += " WHERE B.RN = " + rowNumberFilter.ToString() + " AND A.AutoID = " + autoIDFilter.ToString();
```

Also its good practice to use the `using` statement; SqlConnection, SqlCommand and I think SqlDataAdapter are disposable so you should wrap this with using statements.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT A.* from Experiment A INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS 'RN', "+ "*FROM Experiment) B ON A.AutoID= B.AutoID AND B.RN between 11 and 21 " + "WHERE ......", con);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for respone; I already do that format and I got error;  Ambiguous column name 'iData'.                                                          sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT A.* from Experiment A INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS 'RN', "+
           "*FROM Experiment) B  ON A.AutoID= B.AutoID AND B.RN between 11 and 21 " + " WHERE iData ='ddd'", con);

Comment: I can't see the WHERE you have created by based upon that error change the field iData to TableName.iData.  Based upon your query shorthand it should be A.iData or B.iData

Comment: The BETWEEN statement should be part of your WHERE not your JOIN

Comment: error; "The multi-part identifier "Experiment.iData" could not be bound. when I add the table name                                                  sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT A.* from Experiment A INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID ASC) AS 'RN', "+
           "*FROM Experiment) B  ON A.AutoID= B.AutoID AND B.RN between 11 and 21 " + " WHERE Experiment.iData ='ddd'", con);

Comment: That error means that the table Experiment was not JOIN into the query.  Let me take a peek and see if I can help rewrite.

Comment: You renamed the table Experiment to A, so you need to reference it as A.iData in your WHERE statement.

Comment: thanks; already working I change the Experiment table into "A" Now I go to the next level where Selecting a two table

Comment: sorry I'm New here, how can I mark it as a answer